# Read data from Firebase Storage via REST API

Tags: flutter, rest, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

To overcome the lack of Windows support for Firebase Storage access with **Authentication** in Flutter, I guess we can use REST API then.
I was thinking to use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis_auth) but I do not see any option to log in a Firebase user with Email and Password.
Any idea how we can access Firebase Storage while User is authenticated via REST API for Flutter Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

If I look at the list of [REST APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/) in the Firebase reference documentation, there isn't any mention of a REST API for Cloud Storage for Firebase.

That means the only way to access the files in Cloud Storage for Firebase through REST is to [generate a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/download-files#download_data_via_url) for them on a platform that the SDK *does* support, and then download the data from that URL on any platform where you can [fetch data from a URL](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data).

Comment: Thank you @Frank, sounds like it, yes. But I was thinking about any possibility to use REST API to achieve this!? For example in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103420/firebase-storage-rest-api), we are using REST API but I do not see how we can authenticate based on Firebase email and pass rather than using private key for the project on the cloud.

Comment: also here the discussion is about REST API and Storage read/write [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086557/firebase-cloud-firestore-authentication-error-via-rest-api?rq=4)

Comment: That first link is to access Cloud Storage from a server, not from a client. That second link is about Cloud Firestore (a document database) not Cloud Storage (an object storage). Both seem not relevant to your case, which is why I answered as I did.